# How can I set a constructor object value to be a function of other values?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to generate an object property by running a function on two other properties within the object constructor.

When I run the following code:

```
var ConstObj = function() {
    this.compositionDict = {
        "rock": 0.8,
        "iron": 0.15,
        "gold": 0.05
    };
    this.totalVolume = 10000;
    this.compVolDict = Object.keys(this.compositionDict).reduce(function(prev, curr) {
        prev[curr] = this.compositionDict[curr] * this.totalVol;
        return prev;
    }, {});
}
var tempObj = new ConstObj;
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rock' of undefined(…)
```

I think that this isn't working because the object properties aren't actually defined when the function is being run - but I don't know a good workaround for what I'm trying to do.

I could create a function that adds new properties after creating the object, but it seems like this kind of thing ought to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a matter of `this` not being the correct value inside your `reduce` function. Whenever you create a new closure, such as `function() { ... }`, a new context is created. In order to have `this` point to the proper context, you either have to `bind` the function or you have to use a variable to reference original context.

```
this.compVolDict = Object.keys(this.compositionDict).reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    prev[curr] = this.compositionDict[curr] * this.totalVol;
    return prev;
}.bind(this), {});
```

Or you could use a variable to record the context to use inside the function. It's a bit ugly, but you'll see this kind of thing in all sorts of userland scripts.

```
var _this = this;
this.compVolDict = Object.keys(this.compositionDict).reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    prev[curr] = _this.compositionDict[curr] * _this.totalVol;
    return prev;
}, {});
```

Lastly, another solution would be to use an [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Clearly this is the most elegant of the solutions.

```
this.compVolDict = Object.keys(this.compositionDict).reduce((prev, curr) => {
    prev[curr] = this.compositionDict[curr] * this.totalVol;
    return prev;
}, {});
```

If you can't use ES6, you could use a transpiler such as [babel.js](http://babeljs.io/) that will convert the ES6 to ES5. This is a great way to start taking advantage of new ES6 features yet still being able to run them in ES5 environments.

Comment: Yeah that's okay. That's why I provided 2 ready-to-use solutions first and one he/she might not know about last. The user may not even know ES6 has a feature that solves his/her problem.

Comment: Just keep in mind that browser support for ES6 is [mediocre](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) at best, at the moment. I'm not saying you should forget about ES6, though, it just needs some more time.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer!  I'm going to do more research on `bind`.

Comment: @Cerbrus with transpilers like [babel.js](http://babeljs.io/) you can start using ES6 today; even in environments that don't yet support it.

Answer (score 1):

`this.compositionDict` is `undefined` in your `reduce`, because you're in a different scope.
(that of the `function(prev, curr) {`)

Save a reference to the scope of the `ConstObj` function, then use that reference, instead:

```
var ConstObj = function() {
    var that = this; // Store the reference to `this`.
    this.compositionDict = {
        "rock": 0.8,
        "iron": 0.15,
        "gold": 0.05
    };
    this.totalVolume = 10000;
    this.compVolDict = Object.keys(this.compositionDict).reduce(function(prev, curr) {
        prev[curr] = that.compositionDict[curr] * that.totalVol;
        return prev; // ^ use `that` instead of `this`
    }, {});
}
```